# node.js child_process.spawn() stdout problem

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, string

I am trying to use `child_process.spawn()` in node.js to interact with python script like this :
[code content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fECJu.png)

I want to split the standard out content "String" which come from python function

,but get a confusing result :
[Two line of String: (1)54 math
(2)556 biology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKgDZ.png)

What should I do.I have tried to iterate the String,it look like this String does contain "white space".

Comment: Please give us actual code instead of images.

Comment: Thanks for you consideration,I just slove it.Somehow I can not insert the code content correctly,that is why I use the image.